# In ddd should all calls be routed through the aggregate root?

Tags: domain-driven-design

Should the "user/developer" who wants to do something with an aggregate only be faced with the aggregate root? So should every method I want to call on an entity deep inside that aggregate be "routed" through the root? That would make the root having a very broad interface with a lot of boring code.

Or ist it allowed to traverse and navigate through the aggregate, picking the entity you want to deal with and invoke the method directly on it?

Or have I to ask the root to give me the entity (not allowed to traverse and navigate through the aggregate from the outside) and then call the method on this entity directly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the entity designated as the aggregate "root" is the gatekeeper, so all method calls need to go through him first. if you think about it this makes sense. if you hand out an internal entity, how can you be sure it is used in the intended way and the invariants are upheld? also, now your internal details are coupled and making internal structural changes will ripple throughout the system.

remember we strive to design small aggregate so if the surface area is getting too large that might be a sign your aggregate boundaries are wrong.

Comment: Good answer. I'm not sure where, but I remember to have read that it is Ok to hand out internal entities (by the aggregate root) if they are used short lived or so. This would only couple the entity, not the internal structure (how to get the entity). Would you say this is Ok or are you strict that all entites other than the root are invisible and unknown to the outside? And what about value objects? I think they could be used as parameters and return values, right?

Comment: yes, it is perfectly fine to hand out transient references. since value objects are immutable it is perfectly acceptable to accept/return those as well. in fact, they are part of the domain so you methods on the aggregate should accept those is most cases.

Comment: @HolgerThiemann If it would make sense to actually navigate to an internal entity of an aggregate and call a method on it directly without have the root being notified, then most likely this entity should be an aggregate root of it's own.